# Labeling columns in Pandas but not renaming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, labeling

I have a pandas dataframe with column names. These column names are not meaningful. So I want to make the columns with labels more intuitive and speaking. However, I also have many calculations based on the original names. How can I ensure that I get the dataframes with the labels displayed or that the CSV file shows the labels as column names when exporting, but at the same time that all the calculations in the code are based on the original column names?

Comment: just set the names right before exporting, keep the technical names before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping dict and its reverse:

```
dmap = {'col1': 'My first column', 'col2': 'My Second column'}
rmap = {v: k for k, v in dmap.items()}

# Before exporting
df.rename(columns=dmap).to_csv(...)

# After importing
pd.read_csv(...).rename(columns=rmap)
```

Comment: Thank you this works good for importing and exporting, but what if I would like to show the labels in matplotlib or seaborn or in the df itself? For calculations I still want to use the original column names

Comment: With matplotlib or seaborn, you can use `ax.set_xlabel` or `ax.set_ylabel` to modify the display name of each axis. Unfortunately, [column alias](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11723) is not yet supported

Comment: In SAS for instance there is a possibility of labeling columns and still work with the original column names.

Comment: Well, python is not SAS ;)

Comment: @mozway true but labeling is a useful feature.